# Problem with an aggregated query in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection in mongodb:

```
IDcustomer.     idServicerequired.       ...
001.                  13
002.                  15
002.                  19
002.                  10
003.                  null
```

From this, i want to get the average number of services required by each customer (in this case, the output should be (1+3+0)/3 = 1.34)

I tried as follows, but in this way, for each customer that has required no service, it is counted 1, as if he had required one service, so the average is higher than expected (in this case it would be (1+3+1)/3=1.67)

Answer (score 0):

- first group, check condition if `idServicerequired` is null then count 0
- second `$group` by null and average `count`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$idCustomer",
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $eq: ["$idServicerequired", null] }, 0, 1]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: { $avg: "$count" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j6iFcNGDeQn)

Comment: considering that there is also a date condition, I tried as you said (watch the edited question) but it continues giving me the same output as before

Comment: i can not help without showing date field and values in your documents.